# Algorithm/data structure for a set of modifiable probabilities that always sum to 100

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on a project at the moment which requires me to maintain a variable balance of probabilities between four distinct elements. In my situation, I need to make a random choice between the directions of north, west, south and east, which can be affected and altered at multiple points in the code. The constraints I have:

- There is always only four directions.
- Directions can be randomly selected based on their probability value.
- This probability value can be increased or decreased at any time.
- The sum of probabilities for every direction must always equal to 100.
- The probability for each individual direction can never go below 0 or exceed 100.
- Any increment or decrement in the probability value for one direction should trigger an equal (but balanced) alteration of probabilities for the rest. For example: if one direction has a probability of 30 and has its probability reduced to 0, the other three directions should have their probabilities bumped by 10 points each.
- A user should be able to retrieve a random direction, according to the probabilities, without caring about or needing to know the internal probability distribution. They should also be able to modify the probability for a direction without needing to explicitly manage the probabilities for the other directions.

Is there a neat algorithmic/data structure solution to this? I have an ugly straightforward way that's working for now, but I'd love to know if there's a neater solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each direction a number of points, and don't worry about them adding up to 100. Instead, at any time you can convert the points into probabilities by dividing each point total by the sum of all point values.

For instance, say each direction has 10 points. The sum of all four would be 40, so each direction would have a probability of 10/40, or 25%.

Let's say north is bumped up by 10 points. Then it would be 20 and the rest would be 10. The total would now be 50, giving north a probability of 20/50 or 40% and the other three probabilities of 10/50 or 20% apiece.

Comment: also known as normalizing :-)